# jQuery onlick event is not working in AjAX success call

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am developing a simple blog post where user can comment and likes. I have facing some issue for dynamic content. While user is giving a comment to a post I am adding the the content dynamically.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      
        $('#post-comment-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}').on('click', function () {
            var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
            var comment_content = $('#comment-textarea-' + post_id).val();
            req = $.ajax({
                url: '/post_comments',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { post_id: post_id, comment_content: comment_content }
            });
            req.done(function (response) {
                var content = '<div class="mb-3">' +
                    '<div class="row align-items-top">' +
                    '<div class="col-auto ml-5"><img src="' + response.profile_pic + '" class="rounded-circle" /></div>' +
                    '<div class="col ml-n2">' +
                    '<a href = "/user_profile/' + response.user_id + '"><h1>' + response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name + '</h1></a>' +
                    '<p class="small text-muted"><span class="far fa-clock mr-1"></span>' + str + '</p>' +
                    '<p>' + response.comment_content + '</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-auto">' +
                    '<div class="dropdown">' +
                    **'<a href="#!" id="delete-comment-'+response.post_id+'-'+response.comment_id+'" role="button">' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                    '</a>' +**
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                $('#view-post-comments-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}').append(linkify(nl2br(content)));
                $('#comments-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}').html('<i class="far fa-comments mr-1 "></i>' +
                    'Comments (' + response.comment_count + ')');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Delete ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click','#delete-comment-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}-{{post_comments._id | string}}', function () {
            $('#delete-comment-modal-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}-{{post_comments._id | string}}').modal('show');
        });
        $('#confirm-comment-delete-button-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}-{{post_comments._id | string}}').on('click', function () {
            var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('comment_id');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: '/delete_comments',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { post_id: post_id, comment_id: comment_id }
            });
            req.done(function (response) {
                $('#delete-comment-modal-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}-{{post_comments._id | string}}').modal('hide');
                $('#comments-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}').html('<i class="far fa-comments mr-1 "></i>' +
                    'Comments (' + response.comment_count + ')');
                $('#show-each-comment-{{my_post['_id'] | string}}-{{post_comments._id | string}}').remove();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now its working fine if the code is in DOM and static.
for Dynamic content which I am generating in first ajax success call it is not working. I need to refresh the page to delete it. any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created dunamic modal and links in ajax call itsemf and it worked.